# Is it possilble to add a response body using a customized ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux

I have seen that with version 5.2.0.M1 it is not possible to customize the ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint when using the OAuth2 Resource Server from Spring Security on the Reactive Stack (Webflux).

(See also https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6052)

However, when I was now trying to write my own ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint I was asking myself how to add a body to the http response? The commence(...) method returns a Mono and I have not found a way yet to specify the body somewhere.

Can somebody give me a hint how to do this (if it is possible)?

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile I found a way to solve this problem. When adding just a lambda to the *ServerHttpSecurity* configuration in the *WebSecurityConfiguration* class like this

```
http
  . ...
  .oauth2ResourceServer()
  .authenticationEntryPoint((exchange, exception) -> Mono.error(exception));
```

i can handle the error in my custom implementation of *AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler* where I handle all non spring security related exceptions anyway. This works. I had to copy a bit of the logic from *BearerTokenServerAuthenticationEntryPoint* to get a proper WWW-Authenticate header in the response but it works fine now with a custom body in case of any exception coming from spring security.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

(Spring v2.7.7)
I've referenced the `FormHttpMessageWriter.java` class from the Webflux Framework and found the following solution that successfully writes to the response body without having to create additional exceptions to wrap the `AuthenticationException`.

```java
public class CustomServerEntryPoint implements ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    //References write() in FormHttpMessageWriter.java from Spring Webflux.
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> commence(ServerWebExchange exchange, AuthenticationException ex) {
        //You can customized/parse your message here.
        String message = ex.getMessage();

        byte[] bytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        DataBuffer buffer = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
        return Mono.just(message)
                .flatMap( s -> {
                    ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                    response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                    response.getHeaders().setContentLength(buffer.asByteBuffer().remaining());
                    return response.writeWith(Mono.just(buffer));
                }).doOnSuccess( empty -> DataBufferUtils.release(buffer));
    }
}
```